# PHP Update query no errors but not proceeding with the next page

Tags: php

I need help with the query, no errors or such but it is not proceeding to the next page, see query below:

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','lawadmission');

session_start();

            $reference_number = $_SESSION['reference_number'];
            $citizenship = $_POST['citizenship'];
            $region = $_POST['region'];
            $spouse_name = $_POST['spouse_name'];
            $place_of_birth = $_POST['place_of_birth'];
            $civil_status = $_POST['civil_status'];
            $no_of_children = $_POST['no_of_children'];
            $weight = $_POST['weight'];
            $height = $_POST['height'];
            $degree = $_POST['degree'];
            $school = $_POST['school'];
            $yearGraduated = $_POST['yearGraduated'];
            $elementary = $_POST['elementary'];
            $elementaryDegreeObtained = $_POST['elementaryDegreeObtained'];
            $elementaryPeriodOfAttendance = $_POST['elementaryPeriodOfAttendance'];
            $highschool = $_POST['highschool'];
            $highschoolDegreeObtained = $_POST['highschoolDegreeObtained'];
            $highschoolPeriodOfAttendance = $_POST['highschoolPeriodOfAttendance'];
            $college = $_POST['college'];
            $collegeDegreeObtained = $_POST['collegeDegreeObtained'];
            $collegePeriodOfAttendance = $_POST['collegePeriodOfAttendance'];
            $postCollege = $_POST['postCollege'];
            $postcollegeDegreeObtained = $_POST['postcollegeDegreeObtained'];
            $postcollegePeriodOfAttendance = $_POST['postcollegePeriodOfAttendance'];
            $other = $_POST['other'];
            $otherDegreeObtained = $_POST['otherDegreeObtained'];
            $otherPeriodOfAttendance = $_POST['otherPeriodOfAttendance'];

            $query = "UPDATE applicants SET 
            citizenship = '$citizenship', 
            region = '$region',
            spouseName = '$spouse_name',
            placeOfBirth = '$place_of_birth',
            civilStatus = '$civil_status',
            childNo = '$no_of_children',
            weight = '$weight',
            height = '$height',
            degree = '$degree',
            school = '$school',
            yearGraduated = '$yearGraduated',
            elementary = '$elementary',
            elementaryDegreeObtained = '$elementaryDegreeObtained',
            elementaryPeriodOfAttendance = '$elementaryPeriodOfAttendance',
            highschool = '$highschool',
            highschoolDegreeObtained = '$highschoolDegreeObtained',
            highschoolPeriodOfAttendance = '$highschoolPeriodOfAttendance',
            college = '$college',
            collegeDegreeObtained = '$collegeDegreeObtained',
            collegePeriodOfAttendance = '$collegePeriodOfAttendance',
            postCollege = '$postCollege',
            postcollegeDegreeObtained = '$postcollegeDegreeObtained',
            postcollegePeriodOfAttendance = '$postcollegePeriodOfAttendance',
            other = '$other',
            otherDegreeObtained = '$otherDegreeObtained' and
            otherPeriodOfAttendance = '$otherPeriodOfAttendance' 
            WHERE referenceNo = '$reference_number'";

                if(mysqli_query($connect, $query)){
                    header( "Location: registered.php" ); die;
                    echo "<script>window.open('registered.php','_self')</script>";
                }
                if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
                {
                    echo 'Failed to connect';
                }


?>
```

Comment: It might be the case that you are updating with the values same as present in database.

Comment: Any one of those inputs could cause issue as you have no SQL Injection, protection.  All it would take is a single `'` in any of those fields.  For example `UPDATE applicants SET citizenship = '$citizenship'` if `$citizenship = "it's"` your query is this: `UPDATE applicants SET citizenship = 'it's'` which is a syntax error because of the `'it'` is a complete string, leaving `s'` all by itself to destroy your query.  Please use prepared statements.

Comment: Further this `$citizenship = $_POST['citizenship'];` means you basically have this `UPDATE applicants SET citizenship = '{$_POST['citizenship']}'`  you just didn't know about the `{}` - so there is no input validation and no SQL Injection prevention.  And if you don't think you can get a quote in there all you need is a last name like `O'malley` etc.

Comment: Wow, thank you for explaining me these things. I get it now and works fine on my end, thank you so much!

Comment: Sure, hope it helps you.  I posted an answer... did you see the `and` in your SQL.  I am pretty sure it wont work with `SET` but I don't think I ever tried that...  `SET .... otherDegreeObtained = '$otherDegreeObtained' and otherPeriodOfAttendance = '$otherPeriodOfAttendance` should be a `,` comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is right here:

```
  UPDATE applicants SET
   ...
  other = '".$other."',
  otherDegreeObtained = '".$otherDegreeObtained."' and  <--- and
  otherPeriodOfAttendance = '$otherPeriodOfAttendance'
```

This `and` should be a `,`.

**SQLInjection**
Besides that you are open to SQL injection. As I said in the comments a single `'` in any one of your inputs will wreck your query -via- SQLInjection.

Will take this small example

```
//$citizenship = $_POST['citizenship'];
UPDATE applicants SET citizenship = '{$_POST['citizenship']}'
```

Now if `$_POST['citizenship']` is like `it's` or anything with a `'` in it, this is what your query becomes:

```
UPDATE applicants SET citizenship = 'it's'
```

Now that `s'` will be unmatched and as such it will be a syntax error in your SQL, and you will be right back where you were.  That's the best case.  One thing that could be done is this **(do not try this)**

```
//don't do this
$_POST['otherPeriodOfAttendance'] = "' WHERE 1 --";
UPDATE applicants SET ... , otherPeriodOfAttendance='' WHERE 1 --WHERE referenceNo = ''
//OR
 UPDATE applicants SET ... , otherPeriodOfAttendance='' WHERE 1
```

The `--` is a comment in SQL, so the rest of the query is ignored after that.  So what this will do is update every row in your DB, not just 1 as 1 is always true.   In fact you could probably omit the `WHERE` all together. So just by putting in:

```
  //don't do this either
  $_POST['otherPeriodOfAttendance'] = "'--";
  UPDATE applicants SET ... , otherPeriodOfAttendance=''--WHERE referenceNo = ''
  //OR
  UPDATE applicants SET ... , otherPeriodOfAttendance=''
```

I can basically wipe out that whole table, which is obviously not something we want to do.

I suggest looking up how to Prepare Queries in PHP.  There are plenty of resources on this topic so I won't go into great detail here except to say beside the obvious security reasons, it also takes care of quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use array on your query else you edit your query that would clearly read the the values on your parameters. Also, please consider using `var_dump` or `print_r` for checking.

```
$query = "UPDATE applicants SET 
        citizenship = '".$citizenship."', 
        region = '".$region."',
        spouseName = '".$spouse_name."',
        placeOfBirth = '".$place_of_birth."',
        civilStatus = '".$civil_status."',
        childNo = '".$no_of_children."',
        weight = '".$weight."',
        height = '".$height."',
        degree = '".$degree."',
        school = '".$school."',
        yearGraduated = '".$yearGraduated."',
        elementary = '".$elementary."',
        elementaryDegreeObtained = '".$elementaryDegreeObtained."',
        elementaryPeriodOfAttendance = '".$elementaryPeriodOfAttendance."',
        highschool = '".$highschool."',
        highschoolDegreeObtained = '".$highschoolDegreeObtained."',
        highschoolPeriodOfAttendance = '".$highschoolPeriodOfAttendance."',
        college = '".$college."',
        collegeDegreeObtained = '".$collegeDegreeObtained."',
        collegePeriodOfAttendance = '".$collegePeriodOfAttendance."',
        postCollege = '".$postCollege."',
        postcollegeDegreeObtained = '".$postcollegeDegreeObtained."',
        postcollegePeriodOfAttendance = '".$postcollegePeriodOfAttendance."',
        other = '".$other."',
        otherDegreeObtained = '".$otherDegreeObtained."',
        otherPeriodOfAttendance = '".$otherPeriodOfAttendance."' 
        WHERE referenceNo = '".$reference_number."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

my be problem is die function. remove Die function

```
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
 {
            header( "Location: registered.php" );
            echo "<script>window.open('registered.php','_self')</script>";
 }
```